# Flex data binding with View-Model pattern

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, viewmodel, presentation-model

I'm trying to move toward using the View/Model/View-Model or Presentation Model pattern in a Flex application since it definitely feels like the "correct" way to do things. I have a question about how something should work with Flex data binding though.

Say I have a `Project` model class which contains a bindable name field. I want to make a report to display information about the project. The title of the report should be *[Project Name]* Summary. I want to make a View-Model class to provide the backing for the report. This `SummaryViewModel` class will have a `title` field to provide the report title.

In my report mxml I would bind the title label to `summaryModel.title`, however `title` needs to somehow be bound to `projectModel.name` so if the name is changed in another part of the program the report title updates also.

What's the correct way to accomplish this "two-level" data binding in Flex? Should I be doing things a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a model like this:

```
[Bindable]
public class Project {
    public var name:String;
}
```

And you have your presentation model:

```
[Bindable]
public class SummaryPresentationModel
{
    private var projectModel:Project = new Project();

    public var title:String;
}
```

In your constructor, you can data bind the setter of the model to a function that sets the title:

```
    public function SummaryPresentationModel() {
        BindingUtils.bindSetter(modelNameChanged, projectModel, "name");
    }
```

And then set the value of `title`:

```
    private function modelNameChanged(newValue:String):void {
        title = "[" + projectModel.name + "] Summary";
    }
```

You are then free to bind to the `summaryPM.title` and everything will chain to the UI when `projectModel.name` changes.

You can get more complicated and use a "getter" function on `title` (as opposed to just setting it like I am here), but you need to propagate the change notification.  I is not too terribly difficult to do, but I find that this method is a bit easier to follow.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

No different than any other binding, they will both be updated (both being the place you're putting the title and the summary model).

If you post how you are defining your values I can help you with syntax, but this isn't a difficult binding operation.  Where things get mildly more complicated would be with two way binding.